# Getting alfresco's cancelled workflow

Tags: alfresco

Cancelling workflow means deleting workflow related such as processInstance, taskInstance physically in database, not logically. Therefore, is it possible to get cancelled workflow?
If possible, let me know how with samples.
I also want to get workflow cancellation date.

Comment: Are you interested in JBPM or Activit workflows within Alfresco?

Comment: I am intertested in JBPM workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Activiti workflows, or you have to stay with JBPM because of compatibility issues? Activiti workflows store their history in act_hi_* database tables by default, so it is much easier to get that data than manually trying to trigger cancelling JBPM processes.